# Error writing a file to Azure Data Lake from an Azure function using MSI

Tags: azure-functions, azure-data-lake, azure-managed-identity

I am trying to create an Azure function that writes to Azure Data Lake Store.
I am using Managed Service Identity to, well, manage the authentication stuff.

I have enabled MSI on the Function app. I have also enabled the Function app to access the required Data Lake Store.
And I am using the following code to get a token and write to ADL.
AM I missing something?

```
var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
string accessToken = await azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://datalake.azure.net");
var client = AdlsClient.CreateClient(_adlsAccountName, accessToken);
using (var stream = client.CreateFile(fileName, IfExists.Overwrite))
    {
        byte[] textByteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Winter is coming! \r\n");
        stream.Write(textByteArray, 0, textByteArray.Length);
    }
```

My code fails with the following error.

```
with exception Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.Store.AdlsException: Error in creating file /Path/tempFile0.txt.

**Operation: CREATE failed with HttpStatus:Unauthorized Error: Uexpected error in JSON parsing.**

Last encountered exception thrown after 1 tries. [Uexpected error in JSON parsing]

[ServerRequestId:<Some ID>]

at Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.Store.AdlsClient.CreateFile(String filename, IfExists mode, String octalPermission, Boolean createParent)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding "Bearer " to the access token worked for me. Like thus (everything else remains the same),

```
var client = AdlsClient.CreateClient(_adlsAccountName, “Bearer “ + accessToken);
```

Thanks in part to Arturo Lucatero's Github doc which mentioned this.
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/active-directory/managed-service-identity/tutorial-linux-vm-access-datalake.md

Answer (score 0):

I mainly use following snippet to authenticate and write to Data Lake from Azure Functions:

```
var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
var creds = ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync("domainId", clientCredential).Result;
_client = new DataLakeStoreFileSystemManagementClient(creds);
```

Where `clientId` and `clientSecret` are:

- an `ObjectId` from AD
- a secret attached to it

So basically you have to create a service principal and obtain those particular properties from the portal.

Then I'm able to use following:

```
public async Task AppendToFile(string destinationPath, string content)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content)))
    {
        await _client.FileSystem.ConcurrentAppendAsync("datalakeaccount", destinationPath, stream, appendMode: AppendModeType.Autocreate);
    }
}
```

To write data to ADLS.

You can also refer to [this](http://blog.codenova.pl/post/azure-functions-webjobs-and-data-lake-writing-a-custom-extension-2) blog post.

Comment: Thanks, @Kamo but I would like to use MSI to do the authentication so I can avoid storing the client ID and secret in a Key Vault.